# Google Maps API - How to add floating addres label over a marker

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, when I click on a marker a label pops up over the marker. How can I programmatically activate that label from a starting marker?

Answer (score 0):

Im putting this as an answer for the reason that the name used by Google isnt overly intuitive for this specific use:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

If anybody is searching under the same terms I asked the question they can use this link to find the answer.